# Does memory_get_peak_usage() returns memory of the whole php or just the current execution?

Tags: php, function, memory

Let's say i call `memory_get_peak_usage(true)` and it returns `2.5MB`.

- Does it means that the whole php (all clients) is causing that peak?
- Or does it means that if I have 100 clients acessing the same time, the peak **could** be 250MB?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It returns the peak usage for the current request only.

> From [the doc](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php):
>
> Returns the peak of memory, in bytes, that's been allocated to your PHP script.

---

To remove any ambiguities from the docs:

memory_get_peak_usage() calls the internal [zend_memory_peak_usage()](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/0a243b762cedc9a7c60062d16fc7923015d70fc2/Zend/zend_alloc.c#L2653) function, which returns `AG(mm_heap)->peak`.

`AG(mm_heap)->peak` is reset to `0` in [zend_mm_shutdown()](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/0a243b762cedc9a7c60062d16fc7923015d70fc2/Zend/zend_alloc.c#L1597), which is called in [php_request_shutdown()](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/0a243b762cedc9a7c60062d16fc7923015d70fc2/main/main.c#L1715) at the end of each request.

So it's the peak memory usage for the current request only.

Comment: i've read the doc, and it's kinda ambiguous. it says `memory_get_peak_usage — Returns the peak of memory allocated by PHP` and then it says `Returns the peak of memory, in bytes, that's been allocated to your PHP script.`. Is your answer supported only by the docs or do you have other sources in mind?

Comment: I've verified in the *sources*, the counter is reset at the end of each request.

Comment: +1 for the level of detail. @hugo: the latter of your two points is the answer.

Comment: thank you for the answer. Although it makes me kinda sad that PHP works that way :(

Comment: take a look at http://www.mirror.facebook.net/facebook/xhprof/doc.html#overview if you want to profile memory usages on your server